# matlab multi dimensional legend possible?

Tags: matlab, legend

I have some plotting code in which I would like to plot 10 different types of data points.   I'd like to use 5 colours and 2 symbols.

Basically, if the row or column of my table entry contains a string containg the substring "CSC" I want to change the marker that is used.  c is set outside of this loop and controls the colour of the symbol.

How can I show a legend that shows my list of colours and their associated values, and the symbols with their values.   In text form the legend would be, for example:

```
Colours:
red = One noun
green = a second noun
yellow = another noun
Symbols:
+ = isn't in a row or column that has an entry containing "CSC"
o = is in a row or column with an entry containing "CSC
```

Below is a snippet of my code...

```
for k_ind = 1:length(keepers)
            row = T.Row(keepers(k_ind));
            column = T.Col(keepers(k_ind));

            %Does this row or column contain a 'CSC'?
            if(any(contains(string(T{T.Row==row,'cell_cond'}), 'CSC')) || any(contains(string(T{T.Col==column,'cell_cond'}), 'CSC')) )
                symbol = 'o';
                plot(T.total_read_pairs(keepers(k_ind)), max(T.only_matched_arabidopsis(keepers(k_ind)),0.001), symbol, 'color', C(c,:), 'markersize', 12, 'linewidth', 2)
            else
                symbol = '+';
                plot(T.total_read_pairs(keepers(k_ind)), max(T.only_matched_arabidopsis(keepers(k_ind)),0.001), symbol, 'color', C(c,:), 'markersize', 12, 'linewidth', 2)
            end
        end
end

#Draw the legend down here
legend(...)
```

Comment: You can either directly specify the labels in the call to `legend` or call `plot` requiring as output the handle (e. g. `h=plot( ...`, then use the handles as input for `legend` ([ref. to the legend on line help for the implementation details](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html)

Comment: One way to go is to (1) plot without a legend, and then (2) plot only what the legend would contain (fake data is OK) along with the legend. But the trick is to make the (2) plots transparent. The legend will stay, but the associated plots not.